# Send push notifications from one Pinpoint project to multiple iOS apps

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, aws-pinpoint

I am having two iOS apps managed with the same backend. Can I use the same Pinpoint project to send push notifications to both apps?

There are two ways to configure notifications on Pinpoint:

- AuthKey
- Certificate

If I use the certificate, it will only send notifications to the app corresponding to this certification. There is no way to add the other certificate.

The `AuthKey` is one for all apps, but we have to set a bundle ID when we configure it on Pinpoint. Will it be able to send notifications to the other app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

To setup push notifications you have to generate a push notification certificate which is individual to each iOS app and as far as I'm aware this is compulsory to setup push notifications. So regardless if you use AuthKey you would still need both APNS certificates.

You can see more detail in the Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 0):

I needed two pinpoint projects for two separate iOS apps (whitelabel apps), as it's needed to specify bundle id when configuring push notifications for iOS.

If user is allowed to sign in to the multiple apps, in our case we are tracking lastLoggedIn time to determine to which Pinpoint project id should be used on the backend for sending push notifications / creating campaigns.

The custom Pinpoint project ID also needs to be specified in the client's code, so the tokens are registered properly:

```
 Amplify.configure({ ...config, aws_mobile_analytics_app_id: AppConfig.PINPOINT_APP_ID });

 PushNotification.configure({ ...config, aws_mobile_analytics_app_id: AppConfig.PINPOINT_APP_ID });

 Analytics.configure({ AWSPinpoint: {appId: AppConfig.PINPOINT_APP_ID, ...config }   })
```

We were using older version in this project - "aws-amplify": "^4.3.11". In newer versions, client's config would be probably be a little different.